# Popup on phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

There is an overlay that appears seemingly randomly when I am using phpmyadmin 4.0.4.1 and after about 5 seconds goes away. Is there a configuration that I can change to stop this from happening?

[screengrab http://www.hurwi.net/images/phpmyadmin.png](http://www.hurwi.net/images/phpmyadmin.png)

Comment: Questions: 1. Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? 2. Please provide exact steps how to reproduce this.

Comment: I wish I knew exact steps to reproduce. It really seems to show up randomly whenever I'm browsing, editing, entering sql or otherwise working with a table.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Find this info on the main screen.

Comment: And which browser are you using, as well?

Comment: Phpmyadmin 4.0.4.1. Browser Chrome (latest version) on Windows 8 64 bit.

Comment: If you try with Firefox, what happens?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce it in firefox

Comment: FYI, I updated to 4.0.5 using a yum package and the issue no longer persists. Sorry I couldn't figure out the actual problem for folks.